# Multiple Task<T> or IProgress<T> for partial completion?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-7.1, task-parallel-library, async-ctp

I am using an asynchronous operation that completes in three steps, returning partial results before completion. Originally it's using events to signal progress, and I want to wrap it properly as an `await`able operation (or a chain of them).

To be exact, it's the PhotoCamera.CaptureImage method in Windows Phone 7, which fires events in the following order (with relevant result types):

1. `CaptureStarted`, not that interesting to me
2. `CaptureThumbnailAvailable` (Stream)
3. `CaptureImageAvailable` (Stream)
4. `CaptureCompleted` (bool)

How to wrap this? Currently I'm using a `TaskCompletionSource` and calling `SetResult` on `CaptureCompleted`. It does *not* address steps 2 and 3, the thumbnail and image becoming available. I decided to use callbacks for those instead.

My extension method (leaving out the code for brevity):

```
public static Task<bool> CaptureImageAsync(this PhotoCamera photoCamera,
                                           Action<Stream> thumbnailAvailableCallback,
                                           Action<Stream> imageAvailableCallback)
```

This doesn't feel entirely clean, a mixture of Tasks and callbacks. I know of `IProgress<T>`. However, the progress values aren't of uniform type (Stream, Stream, bool)... and wouldn't that stretch the `IProgress<T>` pattern too far?

Using multiple `Task<T>` that are awaited in order is an option, but that supposes a specific order that I'd also have to enforce somehow. Maybe each task result could contain the "next" task as a member:

```
ThumbnailResult thumbnailResult = await photoCamera.CaptureImageAsync();
...
ImageResult imageResult = await thumbnailResult.NextTask;
...
bool finalResult = await imageResult.NextTask;
```

I still think that I'm somewhat off the mark here. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally i'll create a class for it with 3 methods returning `Task<T>`. The caller will be able to call the 3 methods in any order he wants and it'll always work. if `GetFinalResultAsync` is called first and then `GetThumbnailAsync` then only consequence is that the second `Task<T>` will aready have a result when await is used and it will return synchronously.

```
var photoCapture = photoCamera.BeginCapture();

var thumbnailResult = await photoCapture.GetThumbnailAsync();
var imageResult = await photoCapture.GetImageAsync();
var finalResult = await photoCapture.GetFinalResultAsync();
```

To wait for everything :

```
var thumbnailTask = photoCapture.GetThumbnailAsync();
var imageTask = photoCapture.GetImageAsync();
var finalTask = photoCapture.GetFinalResultAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(thumbnailTask, imageTask, finalTask);
DoWork(thumbnailTask.Result, imageTask.Result, finalTask.Result);
```